# Is this type of question for MESE?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/how-do-you-revise) just came up. I sympathesize with the asker but I don't think this is a good fit here, perhaps Math.SE. Should we allow space for similar questions from now on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, I think yes, it is fitting here. I'll repeat my comment from there:

> If a lecturer would have asked "What learning strategies for undergraduate mathematics should I recommend when I am asked by students?", would that question be more appropriate? Is there a fundamental difference between OPs question and my hypothetical one?

What's interesting on this question is that it's concerned with "how to learn math", not "what to learn". Thematically, it fits well with MESE. You are right, it could have been posted in maths.se as a soft-question, or in academics.se as a mathematics question, but it fits here as a self-learner question, too.

Maybe the focus of this kind of questions needs to be adjusted slightly to get more generalizable answers, including some with citations, but in essence, I think that this question is fine.

As we decided to include self-learners, I don't think that excluding this question is a good idea.

Comment: I completely agree with this and will be deleting my comments on the main question.